# Use __gnu_parallel::sort() with nvcc

Tags: c++11, parallel-processing, nvcc

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with NVCC 7.5 and GCC 5.4.0.

```
testFile.cu

#include <math.h>
#include <parallel/algorithm>
void main(){
    
      <some work is beeing donbe here>

      __gnu_parallel::sort(vector.begin(),vector.end(),<comparator function>);
}
```

I am getting the errors

```
/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/cmath(424): error: function "acosh(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/cmath(442): error: function "asinh(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/cmath(461): error: function "atanh(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/cmath(477): error: function "cbrt(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/cmath(495): error: function "copysign(float, float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/cmath(516): error: function "erf(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/cmath(532): error: function "erfc(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/cmath(550): error: function "exp2(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/cmath(566): error: function "expm1(float)" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/cmath(608): error: function "fdim(float, float)" has already been defined
```

Can anybody please let me know how __gnu_parallel::sort can be used with nvcc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that GCC 5.4 is obsolete/outdated as it has been released 6 years ago and not maintained anymore since 5 years. Why do you use a non-standard GNU functions? Additionally, AFAIK it has nothing to do with GPUs so why do you expect to run on GPUs?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Actually I need to use GPUs for some other task in the same program. For this part I want to use cpu . Is there any method like std::parallel_sort()?.

Comment: Thrust provide functions like that. Alternatively, you can give a look to CUB which also provide lower-level function and generally more efficient ones (Thrust tends to use CUB functions internally more recently). Note that sorting is hard to do efficiently on GPUs so results might be disappointing performance-wise (compared to an optimized CPU radix-sort that is often faster for basic types than std::sort on CPU). This is especially true for "small" inputs (eg. <10 MiB).

Comment: @AnkurGhoshal there is `std::sort(std::execution::par, it, end, comp)` since C++17

Comment: @JérômeRichard Can I use thrust to do a parallel sort in CPU also?

Comment: @Caleth I am using Nsight as the IDE can you please let me know how can I include c++17 support for Nsight!

Comment: Thrust has a `CUDA`, a `TBB` (Threading Building Blocks, CPU) and an `OMP` (OpenMP, CPU, not for offloading) backend, so yes, you can use Thrust for parallel  CPU sort. I don't know how it compares performance-wise with the GNU implementation of C++17 `std::sort(std::execution::par, ...)`.

Comment: Looks like you'd need to [update to gcc >= 9](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) for the execution policy overloads

Comment: Also please use `#include <cmath>` instead of `#include <math.h>` in C++ code. You can then find the functions in the `std::` namespace. This might not fix the conflicts you are seeing though, as I previously observed the functions to still also be available in the global namespace.

Comment: If you can't upgrade your distribution (Ubuntu 16 is quite old, a newer version like 22 would give you a newer compiler), you could use [spack](https://github.com/spack/spack) to build a newer compiler from source without needing sudo permissions.

Comment: @Caleth If I want to have c++17 support, is it mandatory to use gcc>=9 ?

Comment: The support for various C++17 features came into gcc between gcc 3 and gcc 12, as shown in the linked table. Specifically for the parallel `<algorithm>`s, they need gcc 9

Comment: Note that `std::sort(std::execution::par, ...)` is not yet supported by all compiler implementations. For example Clang does not support it yet. I am not sure this is a problem though since you seems to use GCC. While Thrust can compute things on the CPU, it is not the best library for that. It is mainly design for supporting GPU in the first place (with associated constraints like data movements and the design of provided algorithms). Libraries like TBB should certainly be a better choice on Intel CPUs (and more generally x86 ones). AFAIK TBB supports parallel STL algorithms (ie. std::sort).